# Can PhantomJS API be used with grunt (grunt-contrib-jasmine)?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, phantomjs

I am using Grunt to run Jasmine tests through PhantomJS using grunt-contrib-jasmine (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine)

My problem is that I can't figure out how to use the PhantomJS API through this grunt task.

Specifically, I want to simulate a user adding a file to a `<input type='file'>`.
With the command line API you would run a .js file with something like this:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.uploadFile('input[name=image]', '/path/to/some/photo.jpg');
```

(http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html)

Is it possible to run a script like this before the Jasmine tests run?